# Does Apple TV support Netflix/Love Film in the UK?

Tags: appletv

I was playing around with my in-laws 2nd Gen Apple TV and I couldn't find any way of getting to these services.

I'm fairly sure I remember seeing iPlayer and the like in the old UI when I was playing with one in an Apple store but the UI seems to have been updated since then and I couldn't find any features aside from streaming from a computer on the network.

Have these features been removed are are they just well hidden?

Comment: This maybe helpful for iPlayer http://www.infradead.org/get_iplayer/html/get_iplayer.html

Answer (score 2):

- Netflix - yes, just in the last few months.
- iPlayer - no, never has.
- LoveFilm - no.

Comment: This comment deserves a note that it applies to the 2nd generation only - the tvOS based 4th gen supports most streaming services through apps, including iPlayer and LoveFilm's successor, Amazon Video.